# Sharing the same code base and one database

Tags: 8, multi-sites

I would like to have multi-sites that share the some code base and one SQL database in Drupal 8.

Is this possible and recommended? I am interested also in security concerns. Is this safe?

Comment: What information do you intend to share across the site instances? (e.g. users / content / etc...)  There may be different options available depending on your functional goal that may operate differently such as syncing data between different sites but not sharing the database, or running all of the site off of the same code + database but restricting content visible to particular domains.

Comment: On the end I I decided to use multi-sites that share the some codebase. Since there is no sharing of content between sites there was no need to use one database. Before the beginning of making the site planning is very important. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very much possible using the [domain module](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain):

> "The Domain Access project is a suite of modules that provide tools
>   for running a group of affiliated sites from one Drupal installation
>   and a single shared database."

Which is currently under development for Drupal 8 here:

https://github.com/agentrickard/domain

This of course assumes you are not talking about [actual Drupal multi-sites](https://www.drupal.org/node/2297419) which are intended to share the same codebase but always have separate databases.

Comment: I was thinking on drupal 8. They edit my title and in title was writen drupal 8. Yes, my first idea was to have one database and the some codebase in drupal 8. But is that safe? And is this posible without module? if it is not possible, I'll have to settle only with some codebase. :(

Comment: Domain is a well-established module with a robust user community within Drupal so I would say it is safe though you will have to be careful about setting up your user permissions to make sure you are giving access to the right people. Without this module, running multiple distinct Drupal installations on the same database is not possible without radical hacking core.