# "Complex" multisite requirements

Tags: 8, multi-sites

I have a question regarding a large multisite project. The customer has several pages that share the same user right, the media, some content and the users. But they have different themes and some of them have modules that only this specific sites uses. What's the best way to "port" all of this to a new Drupal 8 project?

I think that I have to use multisite so that the different pages can have their own themes and modules. And I can have modules that all pages share. Am I right with this?

But what do I use to share users, content, taxonomy, media and user rights? And what about the database? Can I have everything in one database or do I have to use different databases?

Any tips?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sharing the same code base and one database](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/188971/sharing-the-same-code-base-and-one-database)

Comment: @MarioSteinitz But how can I have different themes on the different sites with the Domain module?

Comment: Because Domain in D7 allowed you to set a theme per domain. Not sure if that is done for D8 yet.

Comment: Drupal multisite is great if you just want to share the codebase (modules, themes, and so on). But the concept of multisite requires different databases and an own file (media) store for each site. Shared databases are possible, but cause a lot of unintended side effects and hazzle on entity updates and Drupal upgrades. You best bet is the Domain module. Unfortunately, I didn't use it in D8 as well. So you'd have to do some research yourself.

Comment: PS.: Down voting started. That's because Drupal Answers is not intended for such broad and multiple questions as yours. Many of them already have answers btw.

Comment: I think there are downvote bots or something, some questions are downvoted within seconds of creation.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz Thanks for your answer. I will have a look at the Domain module.